# Error loading oci8.so and odbc.so dynamic library in RHEL 7.9

Tags: php, linux, odbc, oci8

I installed oci8 into my linux server and tried to connect to oracle DB from my php project but I am getting error like

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ect/php.d/oci8.so' -/ect/php.d/oci8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0**

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ect/php.d/odbc.so' -/ect/php.d/odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0**

```
    **Installed packages**
    php-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-ldap-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64 
    php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-gd-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pear-1.9.4-22.el7.noarch 
    php-odbc-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-xml-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pdo-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-process-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
     php-mbstring-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
```

I don't understand what I did wrong? Can anybody help me

Comment: Are you using apache?

Comment: You need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` path env variables.

Comment: @bassxzero yes I am using apache. How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME path env variables? Do you have any link or any document?

Comment: Don't mix package from distribution and packages from "remi" repository.
And read   https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1676626/how-to-setup-oci8-on-rhel-7-9-with-remi-rpm-repository/1676864

Comment: @bassxzero could you please tell me where do I need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME? /etc/httpd/ in this path ?